# Using PagedList with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Hi Guys really need your help in solving the problem while using PagedList with ViewModel(works perfectly with Domain Model).

I am MVC beginner, here is what I have tried so far.

/************I have one model*************/

```
public class Property
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Edited { get; set; }
}
```

Created ViewModel out of it (will add more properties from other Domain model for the time being using only one Domain model

```
public class SearchResultsVM
{

    public PagedList.IPagedList<Property> BasicDetails { get; set; }

}
```

Controller Action Method:

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string sortOrder, string SearchKeyword, string currentFilter, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.TitleSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "title_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    if (SearchKeyword != null){page = 1;}
    else{SearchKeyword = currentFilter;}
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = SearchKeyword;            
    var sr = from s in db.Property
                          select s;          
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyword))
    {sr = db.Property.Where(s =>   s.PropertyTitle.ToUpper().Contains(SearchKeyword.ToUpper()));}
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "title_desc":
            sr = sr.OrderByDescending(s => s.PropertyTitle);
            break;
        case "Date":
            sr = sr.OrderBy(s => s.Created);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            sr = sr.OrderByDescending(s => s.Created);
            break;
        default:
            sr = sr.OrderBy(s => s.PropertyTitle);
            break;
    }
    SearchResultsVM srVM = new SearchResultsVM();
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    srVM.BasicDetails = sr.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize);
    return View(srVM);
}
```

### My View

While Accessing the ViewModel in View I am not getting any properties of Property Domain Model

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<GH_Final.ViewModel.SearchResultsVM>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchKeyword", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasicDetails.Created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasicDetails.PropertyDesc)
        </td>
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimirs for quick response any clue on How can I convert it to accept PagedList so that i can use it to show paging results?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<GH_Final.ViewModel.SearchResultsVM>
```

Do this:

```
@model GH_Final.ViewModel.SearchResultsVM
```

And instead of:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasicDetails.Created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasicDetails.PropertyDesc)
        </td>
```

It should be:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BasicDetails)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edited)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PropertyDesc)
        </td>
    <tr>
}
```

Comment: You are right. I got the same problem and I solved it by my own.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have your expressions as:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First().Created)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First().Edited)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First().PropertyDesc)
```